# Coded UI - dll file - does not contain ordered test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to run Coded ui test through command prompt using "vstest.console.exe"

My test suite contains an ordered test and few other independent tests.

When i reference the compiled dll using the following command :

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>vstest.console.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\smoketest.dll" /ListTests
```

i can see only independent tests being listed and not the ordered test that i have created.

Not sure what i need to do in my Visual Studio 2015 IDE for the dll to pick up the ordered test?

Build Action is set to None for my ordered test in IDE. (If i change it to Compile, it throws lot of errors like Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected etc)

Can someone shell some idea on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after spending lot of time, i got this working..!

The command to use is:
*vstest.console.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Scripts\SampleTest.orderedtest" /Logger:trx  /UseVsixExtensions:true*

and this command needs to be executed in the following directory:
*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>*

**Note**: I have copied all the folders of my solution from my source machine to the remote machine where i executed this command and also ensured that it contained SampleTest.orderedtest (Not sure though if we need to copy all the folders from the project solution - but it worked!)